# "unexpected token <" in underscore template

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have got following error "unexpected token <" while I have run following code in my app build in backbone.js using underscore template.
Here is code:

```
var data = [{'date':'03 Mar', 'users':5, 'not_ended_sessions':25}]
var rowtemplate = _.template(this.template, {'data': data });
$(this.el).html(html);
```

and here is my html template:

```
<section  class="clearfix">
    <table>
        <thead class="title">
            <tr>
               <th class='date'>Date</th>
               <th>Users</th>
               <th>Not Ended Session(s)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% _.each(data, function(el){ %>
                <tr>
                    <td ><%= el.date %></td>
                    <td ><%= el.users %></td>
                    <td ><%= el.not_ended_sessions %</td>
                </tr>
            < % }); %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="Total Session(s)">0</p>
</section>
```

I have looked various blogs over google, and made changes according suggestions, but still getting same error.

Can someone look into it?
Thanks.

Comment: I think it's `<℅` instead of `< ℅`.... And there is another syntax error in the last td

Comment: @dvenkatsagar, that I have already tried. but no luck

Comment: Even the last td : `<td ><%= el.not_ended_sessions %></td>`

Comment: @dvenkatsagar, you save my day. thanks.

Comment: @dvenkatsagar, Sure. I have tried it in a sec. but denied by stackoverflow. Now I have done it. :) thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the code, the last td

```
<section class="clearfix"> 
  <table> 
    <thead class="title">
      <tr> 
        <th class='date'>Date</th>
        <th>Users</th> 
        <th>Not Ended Session(s)</th> 
       </tr> 
     </thead> 
     <tbody> 
     <% _.each(data, function(el){ %> 
       <tr> 
         <td ><%= el.date %></td> 
         <td ><%= el.users %></td> 
         <td ><%= el.not_ended_sessions %></td> 
       </tr> 
     <% }); %> 
     </tbody> 
   </table> 
   <p class="Total Session(s)">0</p> 
</section>
```